# LibreOffice Writer - How Do I Link to a Bookmark in a Password-Protected Document?

Tags: libreoffice-writer

**LibreOffice ver. 5.2.7.2**

I created a bookmark in a password-protected Writer document (document-1).

I then opened another password-protected Writer document (document-2) and attempted to create a hyperlink in same that would link to said bookmark in document-1. When the **Target in Document** window appeared, it said **Couldn't open the document.**

Any fix for this (I realize why it is happening)? I tried searching for a solution, but could not generate helpful search terms...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is what I got to work:

Make note of the string that names said bookmark in said document-1. You can close document-1 at this time, or leave it open - it doesn't matter.

Open document-2. When creating the desired link, the **Hyperlink** window pops up. Select document-1 to go into the **Path:** databox, then MANUALLY enter said bookmark into the **Target** databox.  Click **OK**.

Done!